# Editing elements in python list

Tags: python, list

So I've got a function that splits a 2d list into 4 smaller ones. The problem with this is I get a copy of each corner of the grid instead of the actual grid.

```
def split(grid):
    tLeft = [row[0:len(grid) / 2 + 1] for row in grid[0:len(grid)/ 2 + 1]]
    tRight = [row[len(grid) / 2:] for row in grid[0:len(grid)/ 2 + 1]]
    bLeft = [row[0:len(grid) / 2 + 1] for row in grid[len(grid)/ 2:]]
    bRight = [row[len(grid) / 2:] for row in grid[len(grid)/ 2:]]
    return [tLeft, tRight, bLeft, bRight]
```

for example,

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = a[0]
b += 1
print a
```

output: [1,2,3,4]

but what I want is [2, 2, 3, 4].

Is there a way I can save each corner of the grid in a variable instead of getting a copy of it?

Comment: `a[0] += 1` should do the trick...

Comment: Are you given the grid in a specific fashion? MattDMo's solution will work for your example but I don't think it answers your question. You're thinking in pointers which, in a language like C is great but it's not so great in a language like Python which doesn't have pointed in that sense. If you are not tied down to the implementation of the grid as a list I would recommend making a grid object. Then you could have a method within that class called, 'getLeftUpperCorner' or something which could then return the values in that portion of the grid while they are still 'attached'to the grid.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

`b = a[0]` *copies* the value from `a[0]` to `b`. So `b` works independent from the list element. If you now increment `b`, the list won’t change. If you want to change the list element, you have to change the list element:

```
a[0] += 1
```